# Counting null values in a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, count

I have a Stored Procedure where it is created a temporary table. This table has several columns and one of them can only have five different values, depending on some conditions.

```
 myID | ... |  myValues
- - - |- - -|- - - - - - -
   1  | ... |  Message 1
   2  | ... |  Message 2
   3  | ... |  Message 3
   4  | ... |  Message 4
   5  | ... |  Message 5
   6  | ... |  Message 2
   7  | ... |  Message 4
```

Now I have another  Stored Procedure that reads this table and returns the number of times that each message is shown on the table.

```
SELECT myValues, COUNT(*) AS Nr
FROM #temp_table
GROUP BY myValues
```

`Output:`

```
  myValues | Nr
- - - - - -|- - - 
 Message 1 |  1
 Message 2 |  2
 Message 3 |  1
 Message 4 |  2 
 Message 5 |  1
```

The problem is when I don't have any one of these messages. My query will only count the items on the table, but I want them to be there with a zero value.

```
 myID | ... |  myValues
- - - |- - -|- - - - - - -
   1  | ... |  Message 1
   2  | ... |  Message 3
   3  | ... |  Message 3

--# WANTED OUTPUT #--

  myValues | Nr
- - - - - -|- - - 
 Message 1 |  1
 Message 2 |  0
 Message 3 |  2
 Message 4 |  0 
 Message 5 |  0
```

I tried using joins, and I was thinking about creating another table but I don't know how to get this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you know all the possible values upfront, you could join on them:

```
SELECT    a.myValues, COALESCE(cnt, 0) AS Nr
FROM      (SELECT 'Message 1' AS myValues UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Message 2' UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Message 3' UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Message 4' UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Message 5') a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   myValues, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM     #temp_table
           GROUP BY myValues) b ON a.myValues = b.myValues
```